# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character (d83d)

Tags: java, android, xml, unicode, xml-serialization

While saving XML data file in my Android app, I get an exception when a user puts an emoji character.
The d83d character is this one, as I understand: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%98%84 - the smily  character.

***The relevant stack-trace:***

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character (d83d)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.reportInvalidCharacter(KXmlSerializer.java:144)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.writeEscaped(KXmlSerializer.java:130)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.attribute(KXmlSerializer.java:465)
```

***The overarching question is***: how do I fix it, so that my users don't have the app crashing on emojis...

The follow-up questions are:

Is this KXmlSerializer supposed to support emoji/Unicode?

Is there an updated version somewhere? I couldn't find it so far.
Is the lib actively maintained?

Who is maintaining the KXmlSerializer?
Is it http://kxml.org/ ? I couldn't find much there...

Wouldn't an updated version, if put on class-path, collide with the Android built-in one?

What other xml-writing lib should/could I use to replace the KXmlSerializer?

***Edit***: I shall add, that the text that the app saves via xml, comes from a standard Android EditText UI widget where the user enters text (I do not do any Unicode-level manipulation on the string).

Comment: This patch might be relevant: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/3f1a5eb%5E!/ but I wonder where to get the right binaries.

Comment: Possibly related issue with Android contact syncing with emojis: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64108 . One project member wrote "i fixed KXmlSerializer in L."

Comment: Do you know how you fixed this issue? I'm also wondering where to find the latest dependencies with that fix. It's still showing 2.3.0 to me which was last updated on 2009 I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I get the same Exception at my test device(API17).Here's the code:

```
final XmlSerializer serializer = new Xml.newSerializer();
final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
serializer.setOutput(stringWriter);
serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
serializer.startTag("", "XXXX");
....
serializer.endTag("", "XXXX");
serializer.endDocument();
writer.write(stringWriter.toString());
writer.close();
```

BUT the code is ok at API21 and API23.

In API17,the key code of KXmlSerializer:

```
// BEGIN android-changed: refuse to output invalid characters
// See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets for definition.
// No other Java XML writer we know of does this, but no Java
// XML reader we know of is able to parse the bad output we'd
// otherwise generate.
// Note: tab, newline, and carriage return have already been
// handled above.
boolean valid = (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0xd7ff) || (c >= 0xe000 && c <= 0xfffd);
if (!valid) {
    reportInvalidCharacter(c);
}
if (unicode || c < 127) {
    writer.write(c);
} else {
    writer.write("&#" + ((int) c) + ";");
}
// END android-changed
```

In API23,the key code of KXmlSerializer:

```
// BEGIN android-changed: refuse to output invalid characters
// See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets for definition.
// No other Java XML writer we know of does this, but no Java
// XML reader we know of is able to parse the bad output we'd
// otherwise generate.
// Note: tab, newline, and carriage return have already been
// handled above.
boolean allowedInXml = (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0xd7ff) || (c >= 0xe000 && c <= 0xfffd);
if (allowedInXml) {
    if (unicode || c < 127) {
        writer.write(c);
    } else {
        writer.write("&#" + ((int) c) + ";");
    }
} else if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c) && i < s.length() - 1) {
    writeSurrogate(c, s.charAt(i + 1));
    ++i;
} else {
    reportInvalidCharacter(c);
}
// END android-changed
```

The reason of Exception,you can read the answer of Stephen C.

At last,I download the latest code of the class **KXmlSerializer** from kXML(https://sourceforge.net/projects/kxml/files/kxml2/2.3.0/).And add to my project,rename the class to TestKXmlSerializer.So use the class as:

```
final XmlSerializer serializer = new TestKXmlSerializer();
```

It's all right to API17,API20,API23.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code that is causing the problem I think.

```
boolean allowedInXml = (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0xd7ff) || (c >= 0xe000 && c <= 0xfffd);
if (allowedInXml) {
    if (unicode || c < 127) {
        append(c);
    } else {
        append("&#" + ((int) c) + ";");
    }
} else if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c) && i < s.length() - 1) {
    writeSurrogate(c, s.charAt(i + 1));
    ++i;
} else {
    reportInvalidCharacter(c);
}
```

(Found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/xml/src/main/java/org/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer.java)

It appears that you are attempting to write unicode code-point 1F604 which is expressed as a surrogate pair as D83D DE04.  Note that the "high" surrogate range is D800-DBFF.

If we feed that into the code, we see that D83D should be acceptable, but only if it is followed by another character.  (The writeSurrogate method checks that the 2nd character is a low surrogate, but you get a different exception message if it isn't.)

So my diagnosis is that somehow you have lost the 2nd character that makes up the emoji.  Check the value of that attribute to confirm / refute that diagnosis before you blame the serializer class.  The checks that it is attempting to perform are totally kosher.

---

**UPDATE**

There are hints that you may be using an earlier version of the serializer which did not support serialization of non-BMP code-points.  (If that was the case, my diagnosis would be incorrect.)

I don't know how you would address that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Edit: I shall add, that the text that the app saves via xml, comes from a standard Android EditText UI widget where the user enters text (I do not do any Unicode-level manipulation on the string). Seems like the "support for non-BMP characters" has been added later in the game (2014) - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/3f1a5eb%5E!/ . What if the target device has an older version? Can I ship an updated version of the XML classes?